# Populating 2 collection views from two arrays of images

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

so I've been searching around and although there are many threads explaining close to what I need, I still can't successfully execute my code. I have two collection views on my ViewController, one with 6 cells running across, and another with 32 cells (4 top to bottom, 8 across). Each collection view needs to be populated from an array of 3 images, they're the same images, just different colors and I'd like to have them randomly populated. I have two cell.xib files, one for each collection view. Below is the .m file for the ViewController I'm working with.

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "CollectionViewCell.h"
#import "RemotesCollectionCell.h"
#import <stdlib.h>

@interface FirstViewController ()



@end

@implementation FirstViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionViewCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.headerViewCollection registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"collectCell"];

    UINib *cellNibRemote = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"RemotesCollectionCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.remoteViewCollection registerNib:cellNibRemote forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"collectCell"];

    self.headLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H\nE\nA\nD"];
    self.remotesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"R\nE\nM\nO\nT\nE\nS"];

    self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"OTIS"];


}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return 1;
};

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(collectionView == self.headerViewCollection){
        return 6;
    }
    else return 32;

};

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"collectCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];



    return cell;

};
@end
```

Here is my .h file for one of the cell.xib files

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RemotesCollectionCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *remoteImageView;


@end
```

And here is the .m file for the nib.

```
#import "RemotesCollectionCell.h"
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@implementation RemotesCollectionCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code

    NSMutableArray *remoteImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red-gps.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"green-gps.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"orange-gps.png"], nil];
    _remoteImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.contentView.bounds];
    [self.contentView addSubview:_remoteImageView];

    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)remoteImages.count);
}


@end
```

I apologize for all the code but I hope it'll help you help me, thank you in advance. Please forgive my noob showing.

Comment: Your cellForItemAtIndexPath method needs an if-else clause like you have in numberOfItemsInSection. You need to check which collection view is calling the method, and dequeue the appropriate cell.

Comment: @rdelmar thank you for your quick response. I understand the if-else part, it's mainly getting the images from the array, and distributing them to the cells randomly. I've posted one array, and one nib, so if someone can show me how to do that I'll be able to figure out how to do the same for the other collection view / collection view cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//In awakeFromNib method define with _remoteImageView.tag=1; so that you can access in cellForIndexPath

```
    - (void)awakeFromNib {
        // Initialization code

        NSMutableArray *remoteImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red-gps.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"green-gps.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"orange-gps.png"], nil];
        _remoteImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.contentView.bounds];
_remoteImageView.tag=1;
        [self.contentView addSubview:_remoteImageView];

        NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)remoteImages.count);
    }
```

//Here whenever the cells are loading load the images after randomizing the array.

```
      -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
                UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"collectCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSMutableArray *remoteImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"red-gps.png", @"green-gps.png", @"orange-gps.png", nil];



 int count = (int)[remoteImages count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        // Select a random element between i and end of array to swap with.
        int nElements = count - i;
        int n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;
        [remoteImages exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
    }
NSLog(@"remoteImages=%@",remoteImages);

                UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];

                imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[remoteImages objectAtIndex:0]];



                return cell;

            };
```

Comment: wow thank you so much. the only issue now is that it doesn't recognize cellView.contentView :/

Comment: In awakeFromNib define UIImageView with tag =1 _remoteImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.contentView.bounds];
_remoteImageView.tag=1;

Comment: Put a break point in awakeFromNib wether it loads UIImageView or not? Or you can drag and drop UIImageView In contentView of collectionViewCell in your interface builder and put its tag=1 It will work.

Comment: I have edited my answer. cellView was there because I coped this from my code. It should be cell. Sorry about that

Comment: Thank you for the edit and your great amount of help so far. I'm getting the following error:

2015-02-09 13:24:03.480 otis[70780:3516198] -[UIImage stringByDeletingPathExtension]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb1820a4c80
2015-02-09 13:24:03.483 otis[70780:3516198] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage stringByDeletingPathExtension]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb1820a4c80'

Comment: Where are u getting this error? are you getting error here UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];

            imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[remoteImages objectAtIndex:0]]; On what action you are geeting this error

Comment: after using exception breakpoint this line is highlighted in green
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[remoteImages objectAtIndex:0]];

Comment: I have updated my answer try now. I was initializing array with UIImage it should be with image name

Comment: I'd upvote it but it says i need more reputation points or something.